# Is it possible to check difference between two captured frames from using VImage?

Tags: objective-c, macos, accelerate-framework

I have a query when we start recording mac screen. I need to take only unique frames only not duplicate frames. Is possible to filter using Macos accelerate framework?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do this using vDSP. Apple's [Finding the Sharpest Image in a Sequence of Captured Images](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/finding_the_sharpest_image_in_a_sequence_of_captured_images) sample code discusses sharing data between vImage and vDSP. Once you have a collection of the pixel values of two images, use [`subtract(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/3241119-subtract) to find the difference followed by [`maximum(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/3241015-maximum) to find the value of the maximum element. If the maximum is less than some threshold, the two buffers are identical.

Note that vDSP doesn't work on `Pixel_8` values - if you're not capturing 32-bit per channel pixels, you'll need to convert to `Float` and that may have an overhead.

Of course, depending on how you're capturing the screen, you may not need vImage at all. For example, if you're getting `CVPixelBuffer` instances, use `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane` to pass the data to vDSP.